# What are the 28 yugas of Lord Vitthala?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, vitthal

Lord Vitthala is said to have been on earth for 28 yugas. What are these 28 yugas?

[Source 1](http://bharathkidilse.blogspot.in/2009/08/panduranga-vithal.html)

[Source 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jUeeAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=vitthal%2028%20yuga&source=bl&ots=_bzHelly7B&sig=owmIjjgwMf0OSfa3ynmi3gmMJPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIjsqctrLaAhUKMo8KHTMbApgQ6AEIkAEwDg)

It is emphasized in his stories and also is sung in his aarti.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a hypothesis than an actual answer.

### Some Background

First, got through the [Hindu units of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time).
Here is the relevant information from that page:
Four yugas(`Satya`/`Kruta`, `Treta`, `Dvapara`, `Kali`) = 1 Mahayuga.
71 Mahayugas = 1 Manvantara.

### [Current Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Current_date)

Currently, we are in the `Vaivasvatha`(7th) Manvantara.
Within which, 27 Mahayugas plus, the first 3 yugas(Satya, Treta & Dvapara) of the next(28th) Mahayuga have already been elapsed.
We are in the `Kali` yuga of the 28th Mahayuga.
Although, there are still a lot of years remaining for the `Kali` yuga, and thus the 28th Mahayuga to end, considering the huge timeline, the remaining years are a "small" time span.

### My Hypothesis

My hypothesis is that the number 28 is related to these 28 Mahayugas.

`Vitthala` is an incarnation/form of the supreme, `Vishnu`. It is also likely that they are actually referring to `Vishnu` when they mention `Vitthala`.
Also I am not sure what they are actually referring to, when they say "earth". May be this universe?

---

Again, this is a hypothesis and I haven't verified this anywhere.
Instead of taking it as an answer, please take it as thought or some direction for further investigation.
Critics from experts on this site are welcome.